# Azure Springboot (Java) pipeline CI/CD to host jar file

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, hosting

I have developed Azure pipeline, its ok sending the jar file to my App service, but that jar file is not running. Even though I initiate it manually doing SSH and java -jar abcjar it shows application hosted at 8080 but its not showing.

**Steps already taken**

1. add plugin in pom.xml"
2. added web.config by FTP on site www root
3. "nohup java -jar abc.jar &"
4. Tried downloading the jar file via FTP and run it, its working fine.

Comment: Can you please share the application startup logs.

Answer (score 0):

I got a success by referring to the tutorial: [Deploy a Spring Boot JAR file app to Azure App Service with Maven and Azure on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin)

1. Rename jar file to app.jar
2. Add an application setting:

[image]